# Validation of my sinwave converter circuit

Tags: h-bridge, low-pass, dc-ac

I'm pretty green and wonder if I can get my 555 oscillator, H-bridge, low pass LC filter validated. I am afraid it can be very painful making mistakes with such voltages.

I plan to use FDA59N30 MOSFETs.

[image]

Comment: Suggestions: (1) Turn off the red arrows if we are to read it. (2) Use the GND symbol everywhere something is connected to ground. It will remove a lot of clutter. (3) L1 is hanging out in space. Shouldn't it be connected? (4) Crop the image to eliminate white space.

Comment: Thanks, hope it is better now

Comment: Due to NPN CE delay, shoot through may result so better designs have ~1us dead time when both drivers are disabled during switch transition. This requires computing dV/dt=Ic/Ciss and adding some margin

Comment: Then Q of LC filter is ratio of Zc(f)/RdsOn ought to be low.. What did you use?

Comment: Thanks,  did learn something new and implemented it.